# Is it possible to jump into a YAML template URL by clicking it in Azure DevOps Server

Tags: google-chrome-extension, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to click a YAML URL in Azure DevOps **Server** and quickly jump into that template?

For example:

[image]

I want to click the template path URL (red arrow in the image above) which is located in the template resource and jump into that template.

Is that even possible?

I tried clicking the link but it's static and not acting as a hyperlink or a .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [this extension called YMLink](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ymlink/fohlplgphadlhkaaamjfiipedeagaheb).
It has 2 features:

1. On your organization's **repos section**, when the extension will recognize a YAML file it will auto scan it and if you are using templates just highlight the path with your cursor and a "jump to" button will appear. Clicking this button will **open a new tab with the template file**.
2. Same goes for **pipeline edit mode** (except here after highlighting you'll need to right click the highlighted selection and the option will be shown in the context menu).

It will also work for files that are not in the same repo.

The extension is free.

[Here is a snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HQ0b.png)